# How to programmatically add a new element in Azure Digital Twin

Tags: azure-digital-twins

Hi I'd like to link a 3d Object to a Twin programmatically, either via the SDK or REST API. Currently in Azure Digital Twins you're able to manually link the 3d Object to a Twin via the Scene Studio, as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-use-3d-scenes-studio#add-elements.

But I've got a lot of 3d Objects and Twins to link, so looking for a way to do it programatically. Each 3d Object is part of my .gltf model that I have uploaded, and each has a unique ID. I have created Twins with the same unique ID. Now I'm just looking to link them.

I couldn't find anything in the Azure docs on how to do this.

I have looked into the call made when doing it manually via the Scene Studio. The payload seems to include an object with 'configuration > scenes > elements'. And inside the elements there is an array of TwinToObjectMapping objects which has the objectIDs and the primaryTwinID. However this call is made to https://explorer.digitaltwins.azure.net/proxy/blob/scenemodels/3DScenesConfiguration.json and sends the entire configuration, which isnt practical.

Any pointers will be appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D Scenes Studio is still in public preview and does not have a public API. There is no way to link twins and models programmatically.